# Open camera from webview

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-studio, webview

How can I open the camera from the webview when I use webChromeClient?

In HTML I use: `<input id="input-1" class="input-upload" type="file" accept="jpg/*|png/*|gif/*|image/*" style="display:none;"/>`

and in Android I use:

```
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
 mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

 mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
     @Override
     public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
         request.grant(request.getResources());
     }
```

with these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" />
```

This is working in the Chrome browser under Android. I have no idea why it's not working in a webview on the same phone.

Comment: Review: formatted the text and code; fixed some spelling errors/typos

Answer (score 1):

You can test here.
I think this is useful for you.

http://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

On Android app Use callbacks.. 
1.) Create a call back class 'ExampleCallback'. Add annotation on the dataResponse

```
   class ExampleCallback{

     @JavascriptInterface
        public void dataResponse(String res) {
//Put your code to open camera
    }
    }
```

2.) add this callback to your webview

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new ExampleCall(this), "Android");
```

On your html page create a java script function with name Android and call it when you want to open the camera.
java script would be like.

```
<script>

    function showAndroidToast(res) {

        Android.dataResponse(res);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: what to put in JS function? I'm not using javascript code to open the camera...i'm just using the input from HTML5

Comment: you can add java scripts within your html pages

Comment: using this function i'm able to open just the gallery/ camera from Android device, but I need to use this function for all devices, like:iOS, Desktop device etc.